# Swift Type Constraints Common Base Class

Tags: swift

We have a helper function that is like this:

```
func + <KeyType, ValueType>(left: [KeyType: ValueType], right: [KeyType: ValueType])
    -> [KeyType: ValueType]
{
    var map: [KeyType: ValueType] = [:]
    for (key, value) in left {
        map[key] = value
    }
    for (key, value) in right {
        map[key] = value
    }
    return map
}
```

and we use it to combine two dictionaries easily like this:

```
let foo = ["fooKey" : "fooValue"]
let bar = ["barKey" : "barValue"]
let combine = foo + bar // ["fooKey": "fooValue", "barKey": "barValue"]
```

It  works great because both `"fooValue"` and `"barValue"` is of type `String`. However, the following doesn't work with error

> "Binary operator + cannot be applied to [String: String] and [String: Int]".

```
let foo = ["fooKey" : "fooValue"]
let bar = ["barKey" : 1]
let combine = foo + bar // Error!!!
```

Is there a way write the dictionary helper function so that when the type of the values doesn't match, find their parent/base class and use that as the return type?

Conceptually, something like this:

```
func + <KeyType, ValueType1:BaseValueType, ValueType2:BaseValueType>(left: [KeyType: ValueType1], right: [KeyType: ValueType2])
    -> [KeyType: BaseValueType] 
{
    var map: [KeyType: BaseValueType] = [:]
    for (key, value) in left {
        map[key] = value
    }
    for (key, value) in right {
        map[key] = value
    }
    return map
}
```

Comment: use 3 generic parameters: one for the left type, one for the right type, with the constraint that the left and right are a subclass of the third

Answer (score 0):

You can use protocols, which all Swift dictionary keys/values have to conform to, to be used in the structure:

```
func combine(lhs: [AnyHashable: Any], rhs: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> [AnyHashable: Any] {
    var dictionary = Dictionary<AnyHashable,Any>()
    lhs.forEach {
        dictionary[$0.key] = $0.value
    }
    rhs.forEach {
        dictionary[$0.key] = $0.value
    }
    return dictionary
}
```